# how to remove extra space between expansion panel childs or elements?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, material-ui, spacing, mat-expansion-panel

As you can see the expansion panel has checkboxes and radios. I want to make those little closer to each other.

[image]

I'm not getting any way of doing this. I'm using Material UI here. Please help me with some solution.

Comment: Could you please add the  source code of your component so we can help you with that, with just an image we cannot figure it out.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).